# Retrieve value of List box on a Form active control

Tags: ms-access, controls

How do I retrieve the current value from any column of a current active control List box.
The list box has data with 3 fields.
I would like the the value of that 3rd column value to be displayed on a textbox when a user clicks a button.

txtBox = [Screen].ActiveControl.column(3)

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please upvote an answer if it helped, or add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`.Column` is zero-based.

Use `.Column(2)` to get the value of the 3rd column.

**But:** if you do this on a button click, the button is the active control, not the list box.

So the only way to do this (except by addressing the list box by name instead of `ActiveControl`) is in the list box `AfterUpdate` event.
(Though in this case you don't need `ActiveControl` either...)